# How do I politely remind a professor to respond to my request for feedback

Tags: communication

I have just started my MSc studies. My professor asked me to do a literature survey and I sent some papers to him 2 weeks ago. He wanted some time to check them, but I have not yet got any email. I think two weeks is quite enough to check them.

should I send him a reminder?

Would it be a polite reminder?

Email subject: "kind reminder"

Dear Prof. XXXX,

I would like to check if you have had time to read papers that I sent to you on X July. I would be grateful if you take a moment to look into it.

I will be waiting for your answer and many thanks in advance.

Best Regards,

Comment: Keep in mind that lots of people take vacations in July...

Comment: Yes, you should send a reminder, but an utmost polite one.

Comment: So writing a reminder is not appropriate now? @ Nate Eldredge

Comment: Nikki, if you want to notify another user, don't put a space between the @ and the name. Instead do it like this: @NateEldredge

Comment: Can you meet the professor in person? I usually come to the professor right away and remind him/her that I sent email/have done something. They are usually super busy. That's why, meeting them directly is one of the most effective way to "send them the message"

Comment: You send your supervisor a collection of papers to read? Bad plan. Even if he agreed to do it, I seriously doubt he has time to read them. And why does he need to? You should summarize the papers and send him the key points. He can then decide if he needs to read some of the papers.

Answer (score 3):

After two weeks, you're within your rights to send a very polite reminder to the professor to have a look over your stuff.

However, I wouldn't make the subject title 'kind reminder'. Be efficient and help them out, make your title 'MSc Literature Survey' or something to that effect.

As for including when you were last in contact with them in the body of the text, I would leave that out. It might just be me but it comes over as a little passive aggressive. If you're wanting someone to help you out, best not to rub them up the wrong way before they've even started.